# How to generate keystore zip file

Tags: keystore

When I try to generate the .zip file, to replace my keystore on google play, this error appears, does anyone know what it might be? I am using PEPK.JAR

The code I'm using is this:

```
 java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=output.zip --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a --include-cert
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Ec9.png)